# Is it possible to modify a function argument? (like & in C++)

Tags: ponylang

```
 actor Test
     fun foo(a: U32) =>
        a = a + 1
```

I want `test.foo(a)` to modify `a`. Is this possible? Thanks

Comment: Got curious and did some searching. You'll probably find your answer [here](https://tutorial.ponylang.io/capabilities/passing-and-sharing.html). (I don't know anything about Pony, though, so could be mistaken...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only modify `var`s at a class level. This is intentional because actors don't like in-place updates -- it really doesn't jive well with lock-free concurrency.

Functions, by default, have the `box` capability, which means that data manipulated by this function are read-only. To ensure that the function can mutate data, the method will need to be declared `fun ref`.

```
actor Main
  var i: U32 = 0

  fun ref foo() =>
    i = i + 1

  new create(env: Env) =>
    env.out.print(i.string())
    foo()
    env.out.print(i.string())
```

[Playground](https://playground.ponylang.io/?gist=690935fcd3a6410e7a4db648f76ce974)

Comment: Is there any reference to this inside Pony's documentation? Or is this knowledge assumed as implicit to all Pony programmers? I was puzzled about this today and could not find any references elsewhere.

Comment: It is briefly explained in the tutorial section for functions in classes: https://tutorial.ponylang.io/types/classes.html#functions It gives a simple overview of what is going on, but for a deeper explanation, the chapter on Reference Capabilities goes through the finer points.